# How to change Accumulo tablet server name to access from a remote client?

Tags: hadoop, remote-server, accumulo

I have been running a single node Accumulo application and it's been running fine as long as the client application was running on the same machine. Now I need to migrate the client to a different machine but running the application gives the following warning that doesn't allow the program to continue:

```
WARN  [client.impl.ServerClient] Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: [localhost.localdomain:9997 (120000)]
```

I was able to connect to the server by editing the `localhost.localdomain` entry in `/etc/hosts` but still want to know the correct solution. I can connect from the client machine to the accumulo server and verify that it's referred to as `localhost.localdomain:9997`

[image]

Now that everything looks in place, if I could just identify a way to refer to the tablet server from the client, without calling it `localhost.localdomain`, I would be back online. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Accumulo services will advertise the address of the server they are running on in ZooKeeper. The service address they use is usually whatever is returned by `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`.

The best solution is to ensure you have DNS properly configured wherever Accumulo and its clients are running, so that Accumulo will detect and advertise a hostname which is also known to external clients. You can also use another name service implementation (by configuring `/etc/nsswitch.conf` appropriately; see `man nsswitch.conf`) so that `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` returns something which would be recognized by an external client. For example, you could rely on the `files` option for the `hosts:` directive instead of `dns`, but then you will need to ensure your `/etc/hosts` has consistent entries on both your Accumulo server and your clients for any IP addresses.

Rather than relying on what is returned by `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` when the service starts, the advertised service hostname can be overridden in Accumulo services by setting the `-a, --address` command-line option when the service is started. This will also affect which address the service listens on (by default, it listens on `0.0.0.0`).

In some of the convenience scripts provided by some versions of Accumulo, the `-a` option is attempted to be automatically set based on what is returned from `ifconfig` and/or what is contained in the `conf/slaves` file. In most scenarios, the behavior of these scripts has the same result as `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`, so using DNS or `/etc/hosts` as your nameservice will be best.